# Suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i\otimes \beta _i)=0$ in $V \otimes_F W$ $(\alpha_i\in V, \beta _i\in W)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, tensor-products, tensors

[image]

I know that if $v \otimes w \in V \otimes W$and $v \otimes w = 0$ then $v=0$ or $w=0$. But if I have to  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i\otimes \beta _i)=0$, then I could not conclude that $\alpha_i=0$ or $\beta _i=0$ por every $i=1,...,n$ ? 
If this happens, one could assume without loss of generality that $\alpha_i=0$ and take as $V_1:=(0)$ and $W_1:=L_F(B)$  Where $B$ is a basis for $\left \{ \beta _1, \beta _2,..., \beta _n\right \}$

Comment: No, for example, $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \otimes \beta + (-\alpha_1) \otimes \beta + (- \alpha_2) \otimes \beta = 0$ is always true but you can't conclude $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0 \vee -\alpha_1 = 0 \vee -\alpha_2 = 0 \vee \beta = 0$ since that's not always true.

Comment: @DanielSchepler 
So what could I conclude from $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i\otimes \beta _i)=0$?

Comment: You can conclude that $\sum(\alpha_i \otimes \beta_i)$ is formally equal to a linear combination of terms $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \otimes \beta - \alpha_1 \otimes \beta - \alpha_2 \otimes \beta$, $\alpha \otimes (\beta_1 + \beta_2) - \alpha \otimes \beta_1 - \alpha \otimes \beta_2$, $c (\alpha \otimes \beta) - (c \alpha) \otimes \beta$, $c (\alpha \otimes \beta) - \alpha \otimes (c \beta)$, when lifted to the vector space with basis $\{ \alpha \otimes \beta : \alpha \in V, \beta \in W \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler 
Then I would have the coordinates of this linear combination are zero since $\{ \alpha \otimes \beta : \alpha \in V, \beta \in W \}$ is base ... And this in what helps me to prove what I want, to find $V_1$ and $W_1$?

Comment: No, in the original example, $$(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \otimes \beta + (-\alpha_1) \otimes \beta + (-\alpha_2) \otimes \beta = 1 [ (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \otimes \beta - \alpha_1 \otimes \beta - \alpha_2 \otimes \beta) ] - 1 [ -1(\alpha_1 \otimes \beta) - (-1 \alpha_1) \otimes \beta ] - 1 [ -1(\alpha_2 \otimes \beta) - (-1 \alpha_2) \otimes \beta ].$$ And this combination has nonzero coefficients.

Comment: The idea here is: suppose that formally $$\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i \otimes \beta_i) = \sum_{j=1}^m \xi_1(\gamma_j, \delta_j, \epsilon_j) + \sum_{j=1}^{m'} \xi_2(\gamma_j', \delta_j', \epsilon_j') + \sum_{j=1}^{m''} \xi_3(c_j'', \gamma_j'', \delta_j'') + \sum_{j=1}^{m'''} \xi_4(c_j''', \gamma_j''', \delta_j''')$$, where $\xi_1(\gamma_j, \delta_j, \epsilon_j) = (\gamma_j + \delta_j) \otimes \epsilon_j - \gamma_j \otimes \epsilon_j - \delta_j \otimes \epsilon_j$, etc.

Comment: Then let $V_1$ be the span of $\alpha_i, \gamma_j, \delta_j, \gamma_j', \gamma_j'', \gamma_j'''$, and $W_1$ be the span of $\beta_i, \epsilon_j, \delta_j', \epsilon_j', \delta_j'', \delta_j'''$.  Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Okay, I'll try to do it!